# GCP Recommendations AI is only for Shopping Sites?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-platform, recommendation-engine, google-cloud-recommendation

We are planning to make a recommendations engine for the features in the app (not a shopping site) and we were thinking about using GCP Recommendations AI. Then, we ran into some unclear areas due to lack of examples.

GCP Recommendations AI is not only for shopping sites, right? I saw a [movie rating example](https://cloud.google.com/retail/recommendations-ai/docs/movie-rec-tutorial#objectives) by Google.

Could you guys please help us with this?